# How to use the built in DI in a .NET MAUI app?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, maui

I have a XAML view that is part of the shell that requires a ctor view model dependency

```
namespace Todo.Views;

public partial class TodoPage : ContentPage
{
    public TodoPage(ViewModels.TodoViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private async void Add_Todo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AddTodoPage));
    }
}
```

The dependency is registered in the MauiProgram.cs file

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Todo.ViewModels;

namespace Todo;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<TodoViewModel>();
    }
}
```

It appears the framework is expecting a default construct for the view, if I create a default construct the DI is ignored.

```
  Message=No parameterless constructor defined for type 'Todo.Views.TodoPage'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried performing property DI but that also resulted in an error failing to create an instance of the dependency.

Comment: Can you try and remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from your `App.xaml`

Comment: This isn't present in my App.xaml. The correct page does startup as I am using the Shell hierarchy.

Comment: `TodoPage` isn't registered anywhere so the DI container can't create it. How is it created? What's the *full* exception, including the call stack?

Comment: *"if I create a default construct the DI is ignored."* - this is by design. DO NOT create a default constructor (despite the error message). Instead, register both view and model in CreateMauiApp (or ConfigureServices).

Answer (score 0):

> *"if I create a default construct the DI is ignored."*

- this is by design.
- DO NOT create a default constructor (despite the error message). Instead, register **both view and model** in CreateMauiApp (or your ConfigureServices):

```cs
var services = builder.Services;
services.AddTransient<TodoPage>();
services.AddTransient<TodoViewModel>();  // OR `AddSingleton`, to share one instance.
```

- [Search `net maui dependency injection`](https://www.google.com/search?q=net+maui+dependency+injection) finds the [DI doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection) that shows this, plus other useful web pages and videos.

---

**BONUS: Easy access to ServiceProvider**

Instead of doing

> `Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IViewModel>();`

as in your work-around answer,
use constructor Dependency Injection to get the provider where needed:

```cs
class SomeClass
{
    // constructor
    public SomeClass(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var somename = services.GetService<SomeTypeHere>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Upon further investigation it appears constructor DI is not available when using AppShell.xaml ShellContent as it requires and calls the default constructor.

I got around this by creating a property of the service and setting it by overriding the OnAppearing method.

```
using Todo.ViewModels;

namespace Todo.Views;

public partial class TodoPage : ContentPage
{

    public IViewModel ViewModel { 
        get => ViewModel;
        set => BindingContext = value;
    }

    public TodoPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ViewModel = Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IViewModel>();
    }

    private async void Add_Todo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AddTodoPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: `xaml` is markup, not code. DI *is* available and works, [as the docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection)

Comment: You should probably check the [MAUI samples](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/18c0627ae678cb97608040825e4c255e789b83ad/7.0/Beginners-Series/MauiApp2/MauiProgram.cs) that use DI. The application starts from `MauiProgram`, not `App`. It's `MauiProgram` that sets up DI and then starts App. The sample shows that both views and models are registered with DI, not just the models. This way, the *host* gets to create the views and inject any dependencies

Comment: First sentence of answer is wrong. `public TodoPage(MyViewModel vm)` would have been called automatically (if that was the only constructor), ***if*** you correctly set up Dependency Injection, as described in links in the previous two comments. Search `net maui dependency injection` finds the doc, and other useful web pages and videos.